# Как ведут себя связанные таблицы с точки зрения памяти?

Tags: база-данных, java-ee

Допустим у меня есть сущность Cars

```
@Entity
public class Cars implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="cars")
    public List<Images> images;
```

И Images

```
@Entity
public class Images {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private byte[] image;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="CARS_IMAGES")
    public List<Cars> cars;
```

Вот, например я хочу просто пользователю показать автомобиль с id=2.

```
return em.find(Cars.class, 2);
```

Я что получу массив, где будет не только имя машины под id = 2, но и массив всех BLOB объектов (картинок) которые хранятся в связанной таблице, и которые соответствуют автомобилю. под id = 2? Иначе говоря, хочу показать пользователю только название, а отправлю ему фотоальбом в пару гигов?

Интересует ответ не только с точки зрения Java, но и базы данных. В БД ведь тоже под сущность лежат таблицы с foreign key.

Comment: Ну в БД они точно лежат отдельно и никак не подгружаются, пока не будут явно запрошены кем-либо; foreign key это всего лишь дополнительная проверка целостности

Comment: (Кстати не по теме вопроса, говорят, что хранить картинки в базе вместо файлов обычно не очень хорошая идея)

Comment: Про картинки в БД, да, вы правы, но это Pet проект, интересно было попробовать). Что значит явно запрошен? В SQL запросе понятно (спасибо за ответ), а когда мы запрашиваем через entityManager используя сущность, там, за кулисами, он явно запрашивает фотоальбом в нагрузку или нет?

Comment: @andreymal зависит от БД, SQLServer пофигу на это ограничение. Дальше больше они ввели отдельный FileStream для таких данных. Если подходить с умом то даже бакапы не отъедут в масштабах вселенского размера.